# AWS API Gateway: Write to S3 then pass all headers and body to client

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I have created an APIGW instance that successfully writes to S3.

Upon my client making a request to the APIGW, then APIGW creating a file in S3, I would like to pass through all HTTP response code, headers, and body back to the client. As far as I can tell, the only way to do this is to create a custom `integration response` and `integration method` for each possible scenario.

Is there a way to create a generic `integration response` and `integration method` that will completely pass through the headers, response codes, and body to the client?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that functionality is already present in the UI for APIGW.  Check the `Integration Response` for your method and add a mapping template if it's not already present.  Then select the Method Request Passthrough template from the dropdown.  It will create a generic response that includes headers, paths, body, etc.

*Note: this feels like a security hole for anything other than debugging, so use it judiciously, IMO.  Maybe start from here and modify the generated template to only include parts that you want to return?*

[image]